# Why is the input() making a prefix error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been coding a top down game and I wrote the basic movement scripts but on line 32 it states that I need a prefix at the end.

How can I fix this ?

Here is the error I get:

> Assets\PlayerController.cs(32,71): error CS1003: Syntax error, ','
> expected

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float x;
    private float y;

    private Vector2 input;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GetInput();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = input * moveSpeed;
    }
    private void GetInput()
    {
        Vector2 input = new Vector2(input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0 input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        input.x = x;

        input.Normalize();
    }
}
```

Comment: `0, input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")`, or choose one of these parameters, if it accepts only 2

Comment: THe [Vector2 contrstructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-ctor.html) does require two parameters, but your second parameter cannot be `0 input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")`. You probably want to remove that zero.

Comment: Remove the '0' before your `input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")` You're trying to assign a third argument to a type that only has two.

Comment: Vector2 input = new Vector2(input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0 input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")); This "Vector2()" can only pass two parameters

Comment: then how can i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is best to understand the similarities and differences between input.GetAxis() and input.GetAxisRaw(). There are two types of incoming parameters: Vertical: Get the value in the vertical direction. Horizontal: Get the value in the horizontal direction. The return value of input.GetAxis() is [-1, 1], and the return value of input.GetAxisRaw() with smooth transition function is {-1, 0, 1}

```
 private void GetInput()
 {
    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if(move != 0){
       Vector2 input = new Vector2(move * Time, rb.velocity.y);
    }

}
```

Hope can help you